# Google Chrome: Diagonal CSS line-through

Tags: css, google-chrome

I just wondered if this is in some way a css attribute:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14645664/fhjfhgf.JPG

Does anyone know ?

Comment: No. The omnibox is not rendered with HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, this is definitely not CSS.

However, that doesn't mean you can't do something similar with CSS.
Start with an element with a specific class, like "slashed":

```
<span class="slashed">True?</span>
```

Then, CSS pseudo elements/selectors to the rescue!

```
.slashed:before {
    content:"╱";   
    display:block;
    color:red;
    font-size:2em;
    position:relative;
    left:1em;
    top:5px;
  }
```

Note that the slash used in the CSS is "╱", not "/", as it gives a better slash effect.
You can obviously tweak it by changing the `top`, `left`, and `font-size` properties.
The end result looks like:

[image]

Note that CSS `:before` won't work in IE7 below, and other (much) older browsers, so you'll want to have some sort of fallback.

http://jsbin.com/ohuxig/edit#html,live

Comment: What is that character, and how do you write it?

Answer (score 3):

```
.strikethrough {
  position: relative;
}
.strikethrough:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid ;
  border-color: red;

  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that is in no way a CSS attribute.