# Dotted Text with CSS?

Tags: php, css

Any CSS masters who know of a way to make a dotted 0?  I had the idea of having a white strike through combined with a white forward slash and back slash as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685483/google-chrome-diagonal-css-line-through), but perhaps there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Use a font with a dotted zero. You can use `@font-face` to include a font that you can guarantee will have a dotted zero.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for this (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cc/index.htm) but as a 0 (zero) instead of as a circle.  Know of a font that has this?

Comment: @JohnBovey: Unfortunately, I don't, although I'm pretty sure one exists *somewhere*. You could make one yourself, I guess. I was thinking a little bit about trying to get FontForge to modify an existing font to make it dashed, but that seems kind of difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. Position a bullet over it:

```
<div>HELL<span class="dottedO">O<span>&bull;</span></span> WORLD</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dottedO {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.dottedO span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Option 2: Using the unicode Bilabial click character (ʘ):

```
<div>&#664;</div>
```

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/ewufod/1

Note the above two solutions may cause issues with screen readers, search engines, etc as you're adding a non-standard character to the mix.

Option 3: Background image

Wrap the 'O' in a span, set it to `display: inline-block` and give the span a background image of a dot. Drawback: that won't print.

Option 4: Use a font that already has this style (embed a web font).

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking for, but if it were wouldn't U+25C9 FISHEYE `◉` work better?

Comment: I guess a visual would help in the original question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom font, or if it's good enough would the U+25CC DOTTED CIRCLE character `◌` work for you?